# Why is using async/await not working in this case for AngularJS service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which calls a service, the service does an async work, when the work (`Promise`) is done I set a property on the controller's scope object.

```
function TodoController(TodosService) {
    let self = this;

    TodosService.fetchTodos().then((todos) => (self.todos = todos));
    
    ... other code here

  }
```

The problem is that using async/await in the service does not update the html rendered elements after the promise is resolved, but using `then` works normally and updates the rendered elements with the fetched todos:

```
    app.service("TodosService", function ($http) {

    // This code does not work, it fetches the todos successfully and also the controller succesfully sets them as a property, but no visual change happens

    // this.fetchTodos = async function () {
    //   let json = await $http.get("...");
    //   return json.data["todos"];
    // };

    // This code works normally as explained above
    this.fetchTodos = () =>
      $http
        .get("...")
        .then((json) => json.data["todos"]);
  }
```

What is the difference between the two cases, because AFAIK (I'm new to JS) both an `async` function and `$http.get(...).then(...)` will return promises, so what am I missing here?

Comment: A function that uses `.then()` will only return a promise if it actually has a `return` statement.

Comment: @Pointy in my actual code I used `return` in the `then` section, but here I used arrow functions for brevity only. Also I want to mention that I printed the return value of both approaches (the `async/await` and the `.then` ) and both printed `object Promise`, but why is one Promise updating the html visuals and the other is not?

Comment: Not **in** the `.then()` callback. The containing function must return the result of the Promise chain, or else it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy can you clarify more what you mean, do you mean that `fetchTodos` in the `async/await` case is not returning a `Promise`? I printed the return value of `fetchTodos()` in the controller and in both cases a promise was returned and the callback was invoked after some waiting time?

Comment: If you're trying to access `self.todos` in that "other code here" block, that will not work. The call to `.then()` will return immediately, before the Promise is resolved.

Comment: @Pointy I know that, also the problem is not in the controller, it is in the service. To narrow down the question, shouldn't the `async/await` and the `.then` blocks in the `service` above be equivalent? If yes then why are they giving different results?

Comment: https://ivantanev.com/async-functions-and-angularjs-1-x-do-not-mix/

Comment: @PetrAveryanov that answers my question, thanks, you can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` ~wraps you code into native Promise and put later code into callback.

`$http` runs http request and then triggers `$digest`

So line `TodosService.fetchTodos().then((todos) => (self.todos = todos));` when u use await will:

- run http request
- run digest
- change controller `todos` field

And as u see digest will not see your changes.

P.S. Things can be a bit more complicated as `$http` may trigger async digest (when `useApplyAsync` is set to true) and then this code may actually work with `await` sometimes(?) but is unreliable anyway.

Comment: Really weird behaviors